# Can't do e Calculations in Kotlin Correctly

Tags: java, android, c, kotlin, math

I'm trying to Calculate this in Kotlin but gives not expected results

[image]

Below is the code in C language and it gives expected result

```
double bsix=1.1890129477526807;
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    printf("value = %f \n",3.08e-4*bsix*bsix);
}

value = 0.000435
```

Below is the code in Kotlin it not give the expected result

```
val bsix=1.1890129477526807
fun main() {
     println("value = "+ 3.08e-4*bsix*bsix);
}
value = 4.354355512964439E-4
```

what I want to do is this

```
3.08e^(-4*bsix*bsix)
```

is kotlin does calculation like this ?

```
3.08e^(-4)   *bsix*bsix
```

thank you very much

Comment: Those are (very nearly) the same number, just displayed differently?

Comment: Read up on what functions kotlin has available for converting floating point numbers to strings and use one that gives your desired format.

Comment: Re “what I want to do is this `3.08e^(-4*bsix*bsix)`”: That does not make sense; `3.08e` is not a defined literal in C or Java source code. Do you want to compute 3.08e-4 to the power of (bsix*bsix)?

Comment: Note that the `e` in `3.08e-4` is not [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).  So if what you're trying to compute is `3.08 * 2.71828 ** (-4 * bsix * bsix)`, then you would need to use the `exp` function in C.

Comment: no not the exp.. the code in C language calculate the Planet positions in space. Its widely available C code..im trying to recreate in kotlin for my software

Comment: I don't see how your C code could be giving you expected results. The `e` in your image of the equation is Euler's number or some other constant, but you are using the E of scientific notation in your C code. But your C and Kotlin *results* are the same, just formatted differently.

Comment: You have correctly implemented the same thing in C and Kotlin.  However, that doesn't match the formula you have specified.

Comment: "the code in C language calculate the Planet positions in space. Its widely available C code" - please give us a link to where you found this code.

Answer (score 2):

Given *b*<sub>6</sub> stored in `bsix`, 3.08•*e*<sup>−4•*b*<sub>6</sub>•*b*<sub>6</sub></sup> may be computed with `3.08*Math.exp(-4*bsix*bsix)`. The result is about 0.010779839926733713.

The C source code shown in the question does not compute the value of this expression. It computes 3.08•10<sup>−4</sup>•*b*<sub>6</sub>•*b*<sub>6</sub>.